# Optimal discrete production / supply scheduling over finite window

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of positive integers *P* of size *N*. I have another list of numbers, *C*, of the same size, but *C* can only contain the numbers {-1,0,1}. My goal is to maximize *sum(P[i]*C[i]) for i=1..N*, subject to the constraint that *-k =< sum(C[i]) =< 0 for i=1..j, all j=1..N*, for some positive *k*.

Examples:

```
If k=1, P=[1,2,3,4], then C=[-1,0,0,1] with sum -1+4 = 3
If k=2, P=[1,2,3,4], then C=[-1,-1,1,1] with sum -1-2+3+4 = 4
If k=1, P=[10, 1, 8, 6, 7], then C=[0,-1,1,-1,1] with sum = -1+8-6+7 = 8
```

Question is what is an efficient algorithm to find *C* given an arbitrary *k* and *P*.

---

Note to tie this to an actual real problem: *P* represents the either cost of production or the reward for supplying in a sequence of time intervals, depending on whether there is a -1 (produce), 0 (do nothing), 1 (supply) in *C*. *k* is the size of a buffer; what ever is supplied must have previously produced and stuffed in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dynamic programming solution that takes O(kN) time:

Let `REWARD(i,n)` be the best reward for indexes `1...i` that can be achieved leaving exactly `n` items in the buffer, and let `REWARD(i,n) = -infinity` if there is no way to process indexes `1...i` that leaves `n` items in the buffer.

For example, `REWARD(1,n)` is `0` for `n==0`, `-P[1]` for `n==1`, and `-infinity` otherwise.

Now, given `REWARD(i,n)` for all `n`, it's easy to calculate `REWARD(i+1,n)` for all `n`. This allows us to use a bottom up, dynamic programming approach to fill in a `k` by `N` matrix up to `REWARD(N,k)`.

The maximum attainable reward is the highest `REWARD(N,0)`, since if `n>0` we can always find a better solution by supplying the buffered items. To produce `C` we walk back the steps that were taken to arrive at `REWARD(N,0)` filling in `C` with `{0,1,-1}` depending on the operation as we go.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the optimal substructure until now. Good stuff, thanks. Still not convinced there is not a faster method though.